# ORACLE read file from url

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, zip

I have a url that download a zip file, inside this one there is a csv file that I want to read into select statement.

Example I have this url: http://www.xyxy.com/test.zip
Immediately you run this url your browser downloads a zip file, inside this one there is a csv file with 5 columns: name, lastname, age, direction, phone

I want to read this csv file called: directions_clients.csv with a select statement just sending the url as parameter.

something like this:

```
Select * from getcsv(getzip('url'))
```

and display each column from the csv file

any idea how to read zip files from url and read also the csv inside of them?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in Oracle, so I assume you have Application Express available. If not, download and install it, it's awesome.

1. Fetch the .zip file from the URL with [`apex_web_service`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeapi/APEX_WEB_SERVICE.html#GUID-B95EA4B6-950D-419D-A2B0-CDB254E1E9F0).
2. Unzip the .zip file into a BLOB with [`apex_zip`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeapi/APEX_ZIP.html#GUID-270BFF3A-5FB1-4089-894E-978608F9BD87).
3. Convert the BLOB into a CLOB with [`dbms_lob.converttoclob`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_LOB.html#GUID-6CCF8174-8A2D-4F3C-A179-A99790BD471D). Make sure you pick appropriate character sets.
4. Convert the CLOB into rows and columns of data with [`apex_data_parser`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeapi/APEX_DATA_PARSER.html#GUID-07E9397C-DF26-40F7-AC73-F46961E1088A).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a special [httpuritype](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_dburi.htm#ARPLS71705) object: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_dburi.htm

Funny example: http://orasql.org/2021/04/25/vblog-funny-friday/